# Rounding Euro cent method

Tags: java

I need a simple method (JAVA) for rounding Euro cent in this mode:

- 1.00=1.00
- 1.01=1.00
- 1.02=1.00
- 1.03=1.05
- 1.04=1.05
- 1.05=1.05
- 1.06=1.05
- 1.07=1.05
- 1.08=1.10
- 1.09=1.10
- 1.10=1.10

Can anyone help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you attempted writing any code?

Comment: "Can anyone help me" We can help you with problems in code you have written, but SO is not a a code writing service. Please post what you have written so far.

Comment: He does not know how to write the code. I think this is a valid question.

Comment: How do you want negatives? (Throw an exception is an acceptable answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double euro = 1.07;
final double dif = euro % 0.05;
if (dif > 0.025) {
    euro += 0.05 - dif;
} else {
    euro -= dif;
}
```

Comment: Using `double` to store amounts of money is a bad idea.

Comment: Why Using double to store amounts of money is a bad idea?? you can post code if return bug or corruption data? Sorry and tanks.

Comment: not work:157.68 -> 157.67999999999998 i need 157.68 -> 157.70

Comment: ops my bad!!! work 157.70000000000002

Answer (score 2):

In general: It is a bad idea to store money as floats/doubles, it only leads to disasters.

If your numbers stay small enough you can make with storing the cent's as integers: 100, 101,... in your example. If it is possible that they will get too large use BigIntegers or sth equivalent.

You can convert the way you want like this: subtract 1 (cent), divide by the granularity (5 cents in this case), add 1, multiply by the granularity.

Comment: Can you please add some reference or reason why float is bad for money?

Comment: sure! http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the right java syntax but this should to the trick:

```
price  = round(price * 100 / 5) / 100 * 5
```